# How to debug javascript file in ASP.NET with Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

In my ASP.NET project, I use some telerik components that aren't usable with Internet Explorer. When I start the debug of my application (using firefox), the breakpoints in my javascript files are disabled, and the application looks like Visual Studio don't look at the css files nor the javascript files. Is there a trick to use them ?

Comment: You can use browser console to debug JS..

Comment: Try adding debugger keyword in script to stop which debugging in Visual Studio

Comment: @AnoopLL The problem is that the Javascript files aren't used at all when I launch the debug.
I tried to add "debugger;" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript debugging in visual studio **is not possible** when we use non IE browser as debugging browser.

The developer tools available on non-IE browsers are the first alternative to the javascript debugging.

The only other solutions are third-party tools which helps to debug on Browsers. E.g.: [Third Party Tool for JS Debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/#JS_debugging)